# Default Postgres privileges not showing on \ddp

Tags: postgresql-9.5

As far as I understand there are set of default Postgres public privileges. I have created user and granted him privilege using:

```
CREATE USER foo WITH PASSWORD 'foo';
\connect bar;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to foo;
```

and I can connect to DB with no issues. Then I taught I must have connection privilege in the default privilege set, since I didn't grant `connect on database` explicitly.

When I do `\ddp` I get 0 rows, and as far as I understood it is a way of checking default privileges per [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).

Can someone help me understand how connecting to the DB is permitted when I haven't explicitly allowed it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-grant.html) PostgreSQL does the following for PUBLIC:

> PostgreSQL grants privileges on some types of objects to PUBLIC by
>   default when the objects are created. No privileges are granted to
>   PUBLIC by default on tables, table columns, sequences, foreign data
>   wrappers, foreign servers, large objects, schemas, or tablespaces. For
>   other types of objects, the default privileges granted to PUBLIC are
>   as follows: CONNECT and TEMPORARY (create temporary tables) privileges
>   for databases; EXECUTE privilege for functions and procedures; and
>   USAGE privilege for languages and data types (including domains).

This implies that to prevent a new user to be able to connect to any database following must be run for each database:

```
revoke connect on database <db_name> from public;
```

Comment: I understand that, tho question was why dont I see those default policies with `\ddp`? Postgres doc says `Use psql's \ddp command to obtain information about existing assignments of default privileges`. I am pretty sure I am missing something, in any case I want to be able to see default policies and explain how and why my user can connect when I haven't allowed it to nor do I see any existing default policies with `\ddp`.

Comment: Privileges on database level granted to PUBLIC cannot be granted with ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES works only on schema and object (in a database) level (not on database level): so  `\ddp` does not display them.

Comment: You should not say 'I want' here: neither to me nor to the PostgreSQL Developement Group (PGDG) who has decided to implement these features which are not standard SQL. If you are not happy with that you can try to convince PGDG to change the software (see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo)  ... or to use something else ....

Comment: question is here so I can understand how this works rather than searching for a hot-fix, like it is noted I am clearly missing out something and I need help figuring out what that something is, Im not experienced Postgres user, debugging rather than fixing is the goal here